# Как создать триггер AFTER INSERT с 'ORDER BY'?

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

Триггер к таблице написан следующим образом:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `opt_torg`.`deals_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `deals` FOR EACH ROW
begin

select * from deals
order by another_iddeal;

end
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после вставки таблица была отсортирована по значениям столбца `another_iddeal`, его значения целочисленные. 
Но при попытке применить триггер выдается следующая ошибка:

```
ERROR 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

В чем проблема и как правильно сделать?

Comment: Понятия "сортировка таблицы" - не существует. Таблица - это несортированная куча. А чтобы понять, в чём проблема, достаточно перевести сообщение об ошибке. В тексте триггера не может быть SELECT-ов в выходной поток. Насчёт "правильно сделать" - правильно задавать нужную сортировку в запросе, когда будете получать данные.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения! Теперь понятно)

Answer (score 0):

Данные в таблице всегда хранятся несортированые. Триггер не сортирует данные.

Или создайте индекс по `another_iddeal` или используйте эту колонку в сортировке.